# error while loading .osm data into POSTGIS in Mac OS Can anyone help me?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I am using the OpenMaps for the first time and I downloaded the file `north-america-latest.osm.pbf`. I am trying to load into PostGIS from where I can import into other DB's.

I installed postGIS uisng `brew install postgis`. It seems to be successsfully installed and running in the backend. Now I am trying to import that file to postGIS and it is throwing me errors.

`osm2pgsql --create --database gis north-america-latest.osm.pbf`

Below is the error:

```
osm2pgsql version 0.96.0 (64 bit id space)

Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
2019-11-14 14:56:07.732 PST [11115] ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist at character 1100
2019-11-14 14:56:07.732 PST [11115] STATEMENT:  CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE planet_osm_point (osm_id int8,"access" text,"addr:housename" text,"addr:housenumber" text,"addr:interpolation" text,"admin_level" text,"aerialway" text,"aeroway" text,"amenity" text,"area" text,"barrier" text,"bicycle" text,"brand" text,"bridge" text,"boundary" text,"building" text,"capital" text,"construction" text,"covered" text,"culvert" text,"cutting" text,"denomination" text,"disused" text,"ele" text,"embankment" text,"foot" text,"generator:source" text,"harbour" text,"highway" text,"historic" text,"horse" text,"intermittent" text,"junction" text,"landuse" text,"layer" text,"leisure" text,"lock" text,"man_made" text,"military" text,"motorcar" text,"name" text,"natural" text,"office" text,"oneway" text,"operator" text,"place" text,"population" text,"power" text,"power_source" text,"public_transport" text,"railway" text,"ref" text,"religion" text,"route" text,"service" text,"shop" text,"sport" text,"surface" text,"toll" text,"tourism" text,"tower:type" text,"tunnel" text,"water" text,"waterway" text,"wetland" text,"width" text,"wood" text,"z_order" int4,way geometry(POINT,3857) ) WITH ( autovacuum_enabled = FALSE )
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE planet_osm_point (osm_id int8,"access" text,"addr:housename" text,"addr:housenumber" text,"addr:interpolation" text,"admin_level" text,"aerialway" text,"aeroway" text,"amenity" text,"area" text,"barrier" text,"bicycle" text,"brand" text,"bridge" text,"boundary" text,"building" text,"capital" text,"construction" text,"covered" text,"culvert" text,"cutting" text,"denomination" text,"disused" text,"ele" text,"embankment" text,"foot" text,"generator:source" text,"harbour" text,"highway" text,"historic" text,"horse" text,"intermittent" text,"junction" text,"landuse" text,"layer" text,"leisure" text,"lock" text,"man_made" text,"military" text,"motorcar" text,"name" text,"natural" text,"office" text,"oneway" text,"operator" text,"place" text,"population" text,"power" text,"power_source" text,"public_transport" text,"railway" text,"ref" text,"religion" text,"route" text,"service" text,"shop" text,"sport" text,"surface" text,"toll" text,"tourism" text,"tower:type" text,"tunnel" text,"water" text,"waterway" text,"wetland" text,"width" text,"wood" text,"z_order" int4,way geometry(POINT,3857) ) WITH ( autovacuum_enabled = FALSE ) failed: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 1: ... text,"width" text,"wood" text,"z_order" int4,way geometry(P...
```

I looked up many resources over SO and the internet. I was not able to understand properly as there seems to be many solutions to load the data.

I would really appreciate if I could get the steps (if I'm doing something wrong) or any GUI tools that will help me import this data by a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Installing PostGIS is not enough. You also need to enable it in each database you want to use.

Connect (via `psql` console, `pgadmin` etc) to the `gis` database and run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Comment: Could you please add the steps.... this doesnt really help me